# List index out of bounds exception in Wrapper Class Deletion

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

I am trying to remove items being displayed on a VF page via wrapper class. The code seems to work fine when a single record is selected but throws index out of bounds exception when multiple entries are selected. Below is the code:

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class SelectEmpRecordController2 {
 //Our collection of the class/wrapper objects wrapEmployee
public List<wrapEmployee> wrapEmpList{get; set;}
public List<Employee_Information__c> selectedEmployees{get;set;}
public Map<String,Double> empatt{get;set;}

public SelectEmpRecordController2(){
    if(wrapEmpList== null) {
        wrapEmpList = new List<wrapEmployee>();
        for(Employee_Information__c s: [select Name,Emp_Name__c,Percentage__c from Employee_Information__c]) {
            // As each employee is processed we create a new wrapEmp object and add it to the wrapEmpList
            wrapEmpList.add(new wrapEmployee(s));
        }
    }
    if(empatt == null) {
        empatt = new Map<String,Double>();
        for(Employee_Information__c s: [select Name,Emp_Name__c,Percentage__c from Employee_Information__c]) {
            empatt.put(s.Emp_Name__c,s.Percentage__c);
        }
        system.debug('map value'+empatt);
    }
}

public void processSelected() {
selectedEmployees = new List<Employee_Information__c>();

    for(wrapEmployee wrapEmpObj : wrapEmpList) {
        if(wrapEmpObj.selected == true) {
            selectedEmployees.add(wrapEmpObj.emp);
            wrapEmpObj.perc = empatt.get((wrapEmpObj.emp).Emp_Name__c);
        }
    }
}

public void removeEmployee() {
    Set<Integer> toDelete = new Set<Integer>();
    for(Integer i=0;i<wrapEmpList.size();i++) {
        if(wrapEmpList[i].selected == true) {
            toDelete.add(i);
        }
    }
    for(Integer i : toDelete) {
        wrapEmpList.remove(i);
    }
}

// This is our wrapper/container class. This wrapper class contains both the salesforce object Employee_Information__c and a Boolean value
public class wrapEmployee{
    public Employee_Information__c emp {get; set;}
    public Boolean selected {get; set;}
    public double perc{get;set;}

    public wrapEmployee(Employee_Information__c s) {
        emp = s;
        selected = false;
    }

}}
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="SelectEmpRecordController2" sidebar="false">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectAllCheckboxes(obj,receivedInputID){
        var inputCheckBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(var i=0; i<inputCheckBox.length; i++){
            if(inputCheckBox[i].id.indexOf(receivedInputID)!=-1){
                inputCheckBox[i].checked = obj.checked;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Show Selected Employee Result" action="{!processSelected}" rerender="table2"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Remove Employee" action="{!removeEmployee}" rerender="table"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageblockSection title="All Employee Result" collapsible="false" columns="2">

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapEmpList}" var="empWrap" id="table" title="All Results">
                <apex:column headerValue="Option" >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputId')"/>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!empWrap.selected}" id="inputId"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!empWrap.emp.Name}" />
                <apex:column value="{!empWrap.emp.Emp_Name__c}" />
                <!--<apex:column value="{!empWrap.emp.Percentage__c }" />-->
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selectedEmployees}" var="s" id="table2" title="Selected Employees">
                <!--<apex:column value="{!s.Name}" headerValue="Name"/>
                <apex:column value="{!s.Emp_Name__c}" headerValue="Employee Name"/>-->
                <apex:column value="{!s.Percentage__c}" headerValue="Percentage" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageblockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Please check the removeEmployee() function for the details I mentioned.
​Can anyone let me know what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume in your list you have next elements

```
[emp0, emp1, emp2, emp3]
```

You want to remove element under index 1 and 3. After you remove index 1, you array becomes:

```
[emp0, emp2, emp3]
```

Now you are trying to remove element undr index 3, which doesn't exist here.

Use new list instead:

```
public void removeEmployee() {
    List<wrapEmployee> newWrapEmpList = new List<wrapEmployee>();
    for (wrapEmployee emp :wrapEmpList){
        if(emp.selected != true) {
            newWrapEmpList.add(emp);
        }
    }
    wrapEmpList = newWrapEmpList;
    //wrapEmpList = new List<wrapEmployee>(newWrapEmpList);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a Look at your below piece of code.

```
public void removeEmployee() {
    Set<Integer> toDelete = new Set<Integer>();
    for(Integer i=0;i<wrapEmpList.size();i++) {
        if(wrapEmpList[i].selected == true) {
            toDelete.add(i);
        }
    }
    for(Integer i : toDelete) {
        wrapEmpList.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Suppose your list has 10 elements and you select 7,8th and 9th element.
So according to your code toDelete will have values 7,8 and 9.

Now in first iteration of your second for loop.
You remove element of 7th index. So new size  wrapEmpList is 9.

Then in second iteration you remove 8th index, New size will be 8.

Now in 3rd iteraion you will try to remove 9th index element which does not exist as the list has only 8 elements. So  **wrapEmpList.remove(9);** gives you List index out of bounds exception.

You Cannot modify a collection/List while it is being iterated.

So workaround will be to use a new List like suggested by **@Ilya Lepesh** in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
    for(Integer i : toDelete)
 { 
wrapEmpList.remove(i); 
}
```

Bug is in this code.

> When you remove element from list list size decreases at run time

so your prepopulated index wont work.

I will suggest you to use another list.

OR

You can directly remove element in first for loop only.

Replace `toDelete.add(i);` with `toDelete.remove(i);`

Comment: I got the issue now. Was very obvious once I looked at it :). Thanks for the answer!